# Copy allure result from docker image to jenkins workspace

Tags: docker, jenkins, pytest

I have a jenkinsfile that uses a dockerfile - and am interested in how I can copy a file from the docker image to the jenkins workspace. Specifically - I am generating allure report on the docker image that I'd like to have published by the jenkins job.
For example

```
node() {
   stage('Start autotest') {
      checkout scm

      def customImage = docker.build("python-web-tests:${env.BUILD_ID}", "-f Dockerfile .")
      customImage.inside {
         sh "python ${env.CMD_PARAMS}"
      }
   }

   stage('Allure report') {
       allure([
           includeProperties: false,
           jdk: '',
           properties: [],
           reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
           results: [[path: 'report']]])
       cleanWs()
   }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything.  When you call `customImage.inside { ... }`, Jenkins automatically mounts quite a bit into the container filesystem, particularly including the workspace directory.  So long as your script writes its result to the current directory, it will be in the workspace directory for later steps, without needing to manually copy files.